# In python - Find the maximum date in a nested dictionary

Tags: python

I have a dictionary that looks like the below.

For the keys '10000ag2' and 10000ag1', what is the the most efficient means to find out which key has the last_event with the maximum date?

```
{'10000ag2': 
    {'last_view': datetime.datetime(2012, 4, 24, 8, 27, 30),
     'last_event': datetime.datetime(2012, 4, 24, 8, 28, 30),
     'last_prid': '300'},
 '10000ag1':
    {'last_view': datetime.datetime(2012, 4, 24, 8, 27, 30),
     'last_event': datetime.datetime(2012, 4, 24, 8, 28, 30),
     'last_prid': '300'}}
```

I expect a list of e.g. 20 top level keys.

thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
max(my_dict.items(), key=lambda x: x[1]['last_event'])[0]
```

Comment: This doesn't find 20 top keys as requested by OP. Probably `sorted`, with `reverse=True` and slicing 20 elements will do.

Comment: I just wanted the maximun of the 20 but the most efficient means.

Comment: Top 20 can be found in O(n), the sort would be O(n log n) so can in theory be done more efficiently, but in practice the dict would have to be enormous for the difference to matter